# Tick checkbox if page is visited via button

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

Looking for some help figuring out how I could add the following functionality:

I've got a contact page on my WP website which has a contact 7 form and a checkbox to Sign Up for the newsletter.

The contact page is accessible in 2 ways - obviously via the menu, but there is also a "Sign Me Up for the newsletter" button on homepage which when clicked currently takes the user to the contact page too. I would like to make it so that when user clicks the button on the homepage, it not only takes him/her to the contact page but also automatically ticks the checkbox that's on there. I do not want the checkbox to be ticked automatically if the user visits the contact page via the menu or any other means.

I guess I'm looking for some php logic, but any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add PHP GET string to button link then read that on other side and make logic like:

if page is `contact-page.php`, then on button add link `contact-page.php?button=true`

on `contact-page.php` read that `?button=true` with PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET["button"])) {
   //echo that checkbox checked 
}else{
   //echo that checkbox not checked 
}
```

or in JS:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("button") > -1) {
      //check checkbox with JS
  }
```

Other option is that you use [JS localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) , when you click a button set `localStorage` `button: true`, then read that on `contact-page.php` and if its true check checkbox with JS

Comment: When dealing with Search Params there's a better way: `const SP = new URLSearchParams(location.search); console.log(SP.get("button")); // "some value" otherwise null` Read more: [*MDN* URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) (If IE is not your concern)